# How can I compile ('build') all TypeScript files in a .csproj C# project?

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

**Context**

Sometimes I would like just build/recompile all TypeScript files in a standard VS 2017 .NET framework C# project (.csproj) without building the dlls, etc. I would be happy even a console command line solution.

**What I've done so far:**

I can use MSBuild to compile everything: `c:\>msbuild.exe my.csproj`. I even figured out that the installed nuget package `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.7.2` is included in my .csproj and has a CompileTypeScript target defined, but unfortunately the `c:\>msbuild.exe my.csproj -t:CompileTypeScript` returns with 0 Errors, 0 Warnings and does nothing. (supposedly looks for the ts files in in wrong place and found none) Note: referring a not existing target gives an informative error message, so the target is definitely found.

**Question**

Regardless the MSBuild idea what I was figured out, I would like to compile all TypeScript files where are in the .csproj project and use the same TypeScript compiler settings what are defined there. How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command worked for me:

```
msbuild YourProject.csproj -t:CompileTypeScript -p:BuildingProject=true
```

The "BuildingProject" condition exists on "CompileTypeScript" task in the Microsoft.TypeScript.targets:

```
<Target Name="CompileTypeScript" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'" DependsOnTargets="$(CompileTypeScriptDependsOn)" Inputs="@(TypeScriptCompile)" Outputs="@(GeneratedJavascript)">
```

Essentially, I had to trick the target into thinking that that the project was indeed building so that it would pass the condition and execute.

I should note that I'm working with TS 1.6 so it's possible that this doesn't apply to to 2.7.2.

Comment: Great, that was the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new MsBuild target that use [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task and tell it to execute `tsc` (TypeScript compiler). `tsc` will need you to pass `tsconfig.json` file so it will know where to find and where to put the output files.

So you will have the following:

```
<Target Name="TypeScriptCompiler">   
    <Exec Command="tsc [path to your tsconfig.json file]"/>  
</Target>
```

Note that tsc compiler should be in your PATH environment variables.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Unfortunately there is no tsconfig.json, instead when I use VS 2017 Project Properties / TypeScript Build tab, all my settings there persisted in the .csproj file. I suppose there is a mechanism, which passes those settings to the MSBuild typescript task.

Comment: You can use tsc without giving to it a tsconfig.json file. That file is here to help the compiler to find where the ts files are so it don't search in all directories.